# angular directive with tables

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm trying to use angular directive with table, but I don't see any data,
when I use list I can see the data and it works properly.
I'm using bootstrap for styling the table too.
I really don't know what I'm doing wrong,

Hope you can help, here are the main parts of my code:

main.html:

```
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="m in users">

        <my-dir my-obj="m"></my-dir>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

app.js:

```html
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/main.html',
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })
 

});

myApp.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    

    $scope.users = [{name: 'john', age: 16}, {name: 'dani', age: 10}];
    
    
    
});

myApp.directive('myDir', function(){
    return{
        templateUrl: 'directive/mytbl.html',
        replace: false,
        scope:{
            myObj: '='
        }
    }
})
```

mytbl.html:

```
<td>{{ myObj.name }}</td>
<td>{{ myObj.age }}</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `<tbody>` for each user.

Try changing to this:

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="m in users" my-dir my-obj="m"></tr>
</tbody>
```

The directive is essentially appending it's template to the element in which it is specified (creating children of that element). So in this case, the children are those of .

Comment: it works now, thank you!
I didn't know that it possible to put the directive inside the element,
what happen actually when doing this?

Comment: The directive is essentially appending it's template to the element in which it is specified (creating children of that element). So in this case, the children are those of <tr>.

Comment: So what is the difference between your first answer(before editing)? 
The directive is also a child of the <tr>